# Scala same fallback for main if and and failure in a Try() call inside the true block

Tags: scala

Looking for an elegant way to have one `doSomething()` fallback in a case similar to:

```
if(boolean) {
    Try(canFailingMethod()) match {
        case Success() => _
        case Failure() => doSomething()
  }
} else {
     doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are not interested in the failure, this may work:

```
Try {
  require(boolean)
  something()
}.getOrElse(doSomething())
```

Comment: Nice. Haven't used `require` before.

Comment: Yep, `require` belongs to a family of methods that can be used to specify pre- and post-conditions for a given code block. You can read more about them for example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-preconditionsassert-assume-require-ensuring/).

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
def attemptWithFallback(flag: Boolean)(work: => Unit)(fallback: => Unit): Unit = {
  Try(()).filter(_ => flag).flatMap(_ => Try(work)).getOrElse(fallback)
}
```